# Sendgrid status 202 node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, sendgrid

I receive the following error when using SendGrid. Even though i get an error the mail is still sent.

> null { statusCode: 202,   body: '',   headers:    { server: 'nginx',
>        date: 'Wed, 05 Jul 2017 18:50:52 GMT',
>        'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
>        'content-length': '0',
>        connection: 'close',
>        'x-message-id': 'EUkSULsjRku6bJTkTFsQ9w',
>        'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
>        'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
>        'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
>        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
>        'access-control-max-age': '600',
>        'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html' } }
>   _http_outgoing.js:357
>       throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Using the following code:

```
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail,
  sg = require('sendgrid')('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');

  var from_email = new helper.Email('my.mail');
  var to_email = new helper.Email('my.mai');
  var subject = 'Subject';
  var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', 'test');
  var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);

  var request = sg.emptyRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/v3/mail/send',
      body: mail.toJSON()
  });

  sg.API(request, function(err, response) {
      console.log(err, response);
      if (!err) {
          res.send({
              message: 'An email has been sent to the provided email with further instructions.'
          });
      } else {
          return res.status(400).send({
              message: 'Failure sending email'
          });
      }
  });
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A 202 is a success message, not an error.  It simply means that your message was "Accepted"

http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

Your code shouldn't be detecting any errors on any 20x response.